# "List indices must be integers not list" reoccurring error

Tags: list, if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x

Could somebody please help me with this python 3 code? I'm having constant problems with it. I've looked at the python wiki but I still can't figure out what the problem is. (I'm used to using LUA, so I tend to make my code in a similar way.)

The section of code I'm having problems with is:

```
if SVDARA[a][0] == coordxy and SVDARA[a][1] == coordxy:
```

It comes up with the error: List indices must be integers not list.

I'm trying to get a FOR loop to filter through a list to find a list (within the list) where the first two (integer) values are the same.

Comment: you should post the traceback. but python list indices have to be integers, so `a` is probably not an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post your `for` loop, but from the looks of it I can guess what's wrong. Instead of

```
for a in SVDARA:
```

You should use

```
for a in xrange(len(SVDARA)):
    if SVDARA[a][0] == coordxy and SVDARA[a][1] == coordxy:
        # Do something
```

`a` will be an integer, and will hold the POSITION in the array instead of the contents of the cell.

Comment: Unless `SVDARA[a]` actually needs to be changed, `for a in SVDARA: if a[0] == coordxy and a[1] == coordxy:` would be better

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just using "For a in SVDARA". I plan to use this a lot of my code, so this is really helpful!